# How Activity will Redirect from browser to Application after payment?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I am new to payment gateway process implementation in Android. Once go through payment process
    from application to browser, after payment process success i am able to redirect to particular
    activity where i left from in some devices. But in **S3 and Moto** devices once the payment process was 
    done it is launching the application from starting onwards. But sometimes it is working fine, 
    is there any due to low memory issue or any othe. please look into this issue.

```
What is difference for these devices working independently or may i need to change any settings.
Please clarify on this  what is happening on situtation by doing payment.
```

**Below is code snippet i am using for payment process :**

Declaration in manifest file using intentfilter :

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.sample.PaymentActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
            </category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" >
            </category>

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:scheme="someschemanameredirecttoparticularactivity" />
        </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

**PaymentAcitivity Code :**

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
     setIntent(intent);
     Intent intent2 = getIntent();

 //Code for use 

}

Please help any one on this, Thanks in Advance.....
```

Answer (score 0):

> But in S3 and Moto devices once the payment process was done it is launching the application from starting onwards. But sometimes it is working fine, is there any due to low memory issue or any othe. please look into this issue.

Yes! You can confirm this by turning on "Don't keep activity" in Developer options. Then the activity should be recreated every time you return to it.

You can handle this by using [onSaveInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and [onRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle))